# Test for item membership in Postgres json array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Let's say I have a table in Postgres that looks like this - note the zips field is json.

```
cities
name (text)    | zips (json)
San Francisco  | [94100, 94101, ...]
Washington DC  | [20000, 20001, ...]
```

Now I want to do something like `select * from cities where zip=94101`, in other words, testing membership.

I tried using `WHERE zips ? '94101'` and got `operator does not exist: json ? unknown`.

I tried using `WHERE zips->'94101'` but was not sure what to put there, as Postgres complained `argument of WHERE must by type boolean, not type json`.

What do I want here? How would I solve this for 9.3 and 9.4?

**edit** Yes, I know I should be using the native array type... the database adapter we are using doesn't support this.

Comment: So how exactly does your JSON look like?

Comment: Exactly in the table there, the JSON is an array of integers.

Answer (score 4):

In PostgreSQL 9.4+, you can use `@>` operator with `jsonb` type:

```
create table test (city text, zips jsonb);
insert into test values ('A', '[1, 2, 3]'), ('B', '[4, 5, 6]');
select * from test where zips @> '[1]';
```

An additional advantage of such approach is 9.4's new [GIN indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) that speed up such queries on big tables.

Comment: +1 This is actually better than my answer, a little enhancement: the query doesn't have to be a JSON array, `zips @> '1'` will be a match too.

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL 9.4+, you should use `json[b]_array_elements_text()`:
(the containment operator `?` does something similar, but for a JSON array, it can only find exact matches, which could only occur, if your array contains strings, not numbers)

```
create table cities (
  city text,
  zips jsonb
);

insert into cities (city, zips) values
    ('Test1', '[123, 234]'),
    ('Test2', '[234, 345]'),
    ('Test3', '[345, 456]'),
    ('Test4', '[456, 123]'),
    ('Test5', '["123", "note the quotes!"]'),
    ('Test6', '"123"'), -- this is a string in json(b)
    ('Test7', '{"123": "this is an object, not an array!"}');

-- select * from cities where zips ? '123';
-- would yield 'Test5', 'Test6' & 'Test7', but none of you want

-- this is a safe solution:
select cities.*
from   cities
join   jsonb_array_elements_text(
         case jsonb_typeof(zips)
           when 'array' then zips
           else '[]'
         end
       ) zip on zip = '123';

-- but you can use this simplified query, if you are sure,
-- your "zips" column only contains JSON arrays:
select cities.*
from   cities
join   jsonb_array_elements_text(zips) zip on zip = '123';
```

For 9.3, you can use `json_array_elements()` (& convert zips manually to `text`):

```
select cities.*
from   cities
join   json_array_elements(zips) zip on zip::text = '123';
```

*Note*: for 9.3, you can't make your query safe (at least easily), you need to store only JSON arrays in the `zips` column. Also, the query above won't find any string matches, your array elements need to be numbers.

*Note 2*: for 9.4+ you can use the safe solution with `json` too (not just with `jsonb`, but you must call `json_typeof(zips)` instead of `jsonb_typeof(zips)`).

**Edit**: actually, the `@>` operator is better in PostgreSQL 9.4+, as [@Ainar-G mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194389/1499698) (because it's indexable). A little side-note: it only finds rows, if your column and query both use JSON numbers (or JSON strings, but not mixed).

Answer (score 1):

For 9.3, you can use `json_array_elements()`. I can't test with jsonb in version 9.4 right now.

```
create table test (
  city varchar(35) primary key,
  zips json not null
);

insert into test values
('San Francisco', '[94101, 94102]');

select * 
from (
  select *, json_array_elements(zips)::text as zip from test
) x 
where zip = '94101';
```